# Keep UITextField focused when presenting UIView as modal

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, uikit

As you can see in the below gif there is a flash as the keyboard momentarily dismisses as the input in the home screen loses focus and reopens as the text field in the second screen gains focus. Is there a way to keep the keyboard open while as the modal is presented?

[image]

Comment: Not exactly what you asked for but perhaps you could just hide the keyboard when you click Open Modal button and open it again on viewDidAppear of modal view controller. Then it should actually look better as the keyboard will finish hide animation and start showing from bottom instead of jumping partially like on your gif.

Answer (score 1):

My not be the right answer but when you are dismissing the view, how are you going about this?

If you are dismissing the first responder, I'm imaging that the first responder is in fact the keyboard on the first view. Are you dismissing the keyboard and then dismissing the view or is it doing that automatically when you are dismissing the view and the keyboard belongs to the first view? Could you try and add some kind of tag to the textField's and then before dismissing the view and moving to the second view, assign the first responder to be the textField in the second view?

Sorry, can't comment yet due to reputation.